# Firefox plugin or software to open file from clipboard

Tags: windows, firefox-extensions, clipboard

What Firefox plugin or software can open a file from the clipboard?

I've asked this on Stack Overflow: [How can I start a Windows GUI program using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059588/how-can-i-start-a-windows-gui-program-using-php) –
but it seems hard to do it only using PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Not quite sure what you mean but there's "Launch Clipboard" add-on for FF.
- You can use keyboard shortcut to launch FF with filename contained in clipboard. AutoHotkey http://www.autohotkey.com/. Create "*.ahk" file anywhere and place smth like this into it:

  ```
  #H::
  clipboard = %clipboard%
  EnvGet, programs, ProgramFiles(x86)
  StringReplace, programs, programs, \, \\, All
  Run, "%programs%\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" file:///%clipboard%
  return
  ```

Run the script (H icon will appear in tray).

The script above will open things like "c:\docs\file.html" (contained in clipboard) in FF when you press Win+H (#H). Look through autohotkey documentation to define any other hotkey. You can also extend the script's functionality to store clipboard into a file and open it with FF.